# connecting signal in matplotlib + gtk

Tags: events, gtk, matplotlib

I am developing a matplotlib application in gtk, and I would like to abstract plotting-related stuff in a python class, but at the same time, I would also like to have the ability to interact with the graph via keystrokes. My class definition looks like this:

```
class Plot:
    def __init__(self, data, datatype, xlabel=None, ylabel=None, xtics=None, ytics=None):
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=72)
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key)

    def on_key(self, event):
        print 'pressed'
```

and I drop the plot in the main window with this:

```
x = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = numpy.sin(x)
plot = Plot([x,y], 'line', 'xlabel', 'ylabel')
vbox.pack_start(plot.plotbox)
```

where vbox is just a gtkbox. Now, the plot is displayed properly, but I can't interact with it, i.e., I can't enter the function on_key, when I press a key. 
Could someone point out what is missing?

Many thanks,

v923z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was: plot's scope is the **init** function, so it becomes inactive once the **init** function returns. One has to define plot as

```
self.plot = Plot([x,y], 'line', 'xlabel', 'ylabel')
vbox.pack_start(self.plot.plotbox)
```

With this, the plot reacts to key presses.

v923z